# Matplotlib right y-axis numbers in line

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to make one plot with multiple y-axis with this example: https://matplotlib.org/faq/howto_faq-1.pdf

Here is the link with the source code https://matplotlib.org/faq/howto_faq.html

I'm a little dissatisfied about the alignment of the right y-axis.

```
1.00
0.50
0.00
-0.50
-1.00
```

Is it possible to change the alignment and get the numbers in line, like:

```
 1.00
 0.50
 0.00
-0.50
-1.00
```

Is there any way to add leading spaces to tick marks?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please insert your code in your post, rather than linking it. Thanks!

Comment: The dupe I marked is about colorbars, however the same solution can be applied to the second y axis

Answer (score 0):

Use the following three lines to set horizontal alignment and move labels outside the plot:

```
for label in ax2.get_yticklabels():
    label.set_horizontalalignment('right')
ax2.get_yaxis().set_tick_params(pad=40)
```